# Nginx как применить rewrite к location?

Tags: nginx

Имею картинку в директории:

```
www/Directory/image.jpg
```

Nginx конфиг:

```
 location /test {
     root /www;
 }
```

Хочу получить картинку по адресу: http://localhost/test/image.jpg

Как такое сделать? Rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй [alias](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

```
location /test/ {
    alias /www/Directory/;
}
```